# JSaddle - What's the magic of the h$ prefix in the argument of the jsg1 function

Tags: haskell

The functions [jsg](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0/docs/Language-Javascript-JSaddle-Object.html#v:jsg) 
and [jsg1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0/docs/Language-Javascript-JSaddle-Object.html#v:jsg1) 
of the [jsaddle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0)
package allow to do low level calls to Javascript functions.

The jsaddle package even has some [examples of how to use jsg1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0/docs/src/JavaScript-TypedArray-Internal.html#uint8ArrayFrom) eg:

`uint8ArrayFrom (SomeJSArray a) = SomeTypedArray <$> jsg "Uint8Array" ^. js1 "from" a`

`uint16ArrayFrom (SomeJSArray a) = SomeTypedArray <$> jsg "Uint16Array" ^. js1 "from" a`

In both cases, the parameters *Uint8Array* and *Uint16Array* are well known global names in Javascript. 
It's easy to find Javascript documentation about all these names.

The examples of the usage of the function *jsg1* eg 
[here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0/docs/src/GHCJS-Buffer.html#createFromArrayBuffer)
and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-0.9.4.0/docs/src/GHCJS-Buffer.html#fromByteString), however, use stange strings
like `h$wrapBuffer` and `h$newByteArrayFromBase64String`. Googling these strings, specially on *h$newByteArrayFromBase64String*, does not give any meaningful results.

What is the meaning of the strings in the argument of the *jsg1* function? Where are they defined? Which other strings are possible as jsg1 arguments?
Is the *h$* prefix a convention, that triggers some hidden magic?

Comment: Having never used ghcjs before (and therefore my guesses being a priori suspect), I would guess these are Javascript function names provided by the ghcjs runtime.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: One reason why I think your hyothesis is wrong: You can compile Haskell JSaddle programs with GHC and they run in WebkitGtk. So there is no GHCJS involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic.  The `h$` prefix is just to avoid clashing with anything likely to be used by other JavaScript libraries.

[These modules](https://github.com/ghcjs/jsaddle/blob/master/jsaddle/jsaddle.cabal#L53) are only exposed in the else branch of an `if impl(ghcjs)` because they are provided by ghcjs-base package when compiling with GHCJS.

When compiling with GHC the two `h$` functions will be loaded into the JavaScript context along with the other JavaScript needed by jsaddle [here](https://github.com/ghcjs/jsaddle/blob/master/jsaddle/src/Language/Javascript/JSaddle/Run/Files.hs#L457).